# Jsoup loop through ol li tags

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get product information from a shop's webpage, but the list is built with ol and li tags and I haven't found a clear example for myself. I would need product name and price.

Page:
https://www.selver.ee/joogid/lahja-alkohol/punased-veinid?p=1

Table begins with: `ol class="row products-grid" id="products-grid"`

Comment: if it is ol and li tags then its a list not a table

Comment: Thank you! I changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following : it will get the list of product details

```
#products-grid li
```

[image]

It will get the price details

```
#products-grid li .price-box
```

[image]
It will get the product details

```
#products-grid li .product-name
```

[image]